# React lifecycle methods. When does an app render to the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read numerous articles on React's lifecycle methods and I can't seem to get an answer to a question I'm struggling with.

I have a relatively simple app that I've written that renders:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('Root'))
```

Root looks like:

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
</ApolloProvider>
```

App has a few components inside it.

I have placed `console.logs` within each components `componentDidMount` methods and the order they log is as follows:

1. Component 1 (child to 2)
2. Component 2 (child to APP)
3. App (child to BrowserRouter)
4. BrowserRouter (child to ApolloProvider)
5. ApolloProvider (Child to Root)

My question is, once Component 2 for example has rendered and `componentDidMount` executed, does that mean the component is visible on the screen or do all the components have to mount first to the virtual DOM, before the actual browser DOM is updated?

When does a React app actually update the browser DOM?

Comment: Since the real dimensions of components' DOM elements are known inside 'componentDiDMount' I think the whole DOM is built at this time. Not 100% sure though :p (i.e. all components have to mount before the DOM is updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading and research, I think the following example might give you some light:

Imagine I have 3 Components: `A, B, C`, such that:

```
<A>
 <B>
  <C/>
 </B>
</A>
```

Now, the order in which the rendering, DOM updation(painting) and life cycle `Did` methods get executed are:

```
A.render() -> B.render() -> C.render() -> Reconciliation and DOM update -> C.componentDidMount() -> B.componentDidMount() -> A.componentDidMount()
```

**`render()`** function returns a new element, and this is input to the reconciliation process, which is responsible for DOM updating. If the component has children, the childrens' `render` methods are called, and only after the last child in the tree does the browser painting happens.

> *My question is, once Component 2 for example has rendered and `componentDidMount` executed, does that mean the component is visible on the screen or ....*

**Yes**, I'd like to think so. `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` are called only after the actual DOM updation has taken place, [always](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10878#issuecomment-332570696).

Also see https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/how-virtual-dom-and-diffing-works-in-react-6fc805f9f84e, which looks like an in-depth explanation of how updation in React works.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dane. Reviewing your finding later today. Cheers